# Error when use UIAplication.getUIApllication.pushScreen(screen) on Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have a "Back" button that I created.
Action for it is ----- **UIAplication.getUIApllication.pushScreen(screen1)** 
I did so because I want to refresh screen 1 when I cick "Back ".

But there have an error that " OutOfMemoryError" when I click "Back" few times.
If I replace with -  **UIAplication.getUIApllication.popScreen(this)** , there have no error .
*But I really want to refresh screen1*.
Why I gotthis error ? How to solve it ? ( I use Persistenobject to save data for my app ).
Please help me . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pushing the same screen again adds additional screen to stack and takes additional memory.
And it is logical that you get outofmemory error.

If you want to refresh field's/manager's contents use [invalidate()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.1api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#invalidate%28%29) method of a particular field or manager.

Answer (score 2):

You can try popping the old screen1 and then pushing it again:

```
UIAplication.getUIApllication.popScreen(getScreenBelow());
UIAplication.getUIApllication.pushScreen(new screen1());
```